# Calling web service from another ejb on startup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jbossws

Using jboss-esb 5.1.0.GA

I have a web service that an EJB that I have makes calls on when it is started.  This EJB may be installed in the same JBoss instance as the web service.  If I start JBoss, let it come up completely, then deploy my EJB into the same instance, all is well.  However, if I leave it deployed and restart JBoss, when the EJB gets to the point where it makes a call on the web service, the Application Server start-up process hangs.  Now the WebService was deployed prior to the EJB according to the logs.  It acts like the web server that is serving the WS calls is not yet up either.  I can try to access the WSDL via a web browser and that fails until the JBoss instance is fully started.  i can see if I have my dependencies wrong and it would error out on deployment, but I get no error, it just hangs indefinitely.  Any ideas where to go from here.  Any more information you need?

Thanks,
-Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears there is a bug in the version of JBoss that we are using.  We were required to register for an event to notify us when JBoss was up, then we made our WS calls and things work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure the order of deployment if you bundle your webservice war and ejb jar into one single ear file. In this case the ejb jar is always deployed first.